# Regular expression single space

Tags: regex, string, expression, whitespace

I'm trying to make a regular expression to validate this pattern:

> This is a text
>   [TEXT][SINGLE SPACE][TEXT][SINGLE SPACE][TEXT][SINGLE SPACE][TEXT]
>   A personal name
>   William Smith
>   [TEXT][SINGLE SPACE][TEXT]
>   Another text 
>   [TEXT][SINGLE SPACE][TEXT][SINGLE SPACE]

The pattern will contain the next rules:

- Not start with any space
- The string can contain just a single space between words or a single space at the end of the string

I have this regular expression

> /^[[A-Za-z0-9]+\s?[A-Za-z0-9]*]{0,10}$/

But I don't know how to repeat the pattern and make it 10 of length

** Edit **

To make a more understandable, I'm working on a jQuery plugin that bind a keypress event to a input text element, and then add an expression to validate in each key pressed the text, is like a masked textbox, so to apply the rules for a mask that accept just alphanumeric characters and a space between the words I need the expression validate each key pressed like this

T
Th
This
This
This i
This is
This is
This is a
This is a
This is a t
This is a te
This is a tex
This is a text

Comment: What do you mean by `[TEXT]`? Should that always be the same, repeating itself? Or what does qualify a "text"?

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question ? I cannot understand your question...

Comment: I have found the expression that I needed based on the response of [@ DragoonWraith](http://stackoverflow.com/users/778430/dragoonwraith): `/^[(a-zA-Z01-9)\s?]{0,10}$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, well, I *think* I've understood the requirements correctly.

First, this matches a single word followed by exactly one space:

```
/[a-zA-Z01-9]+ /
```

Then we need to repeat that 10 times, right? Starting from the beginning?

```
/^([a-zA-Z01-9]+ ){10}/
```

But the trailing space is optional, yes?

```
/^([a-zA-Z01-9]+ ){9}[a-zA-Z01-9]+ ?$/
```

Also, it would probably be better to use `\w` rather than `[a-zA-Z01-9]`.<sup>1</sup> And `\s` would match any whitespace, which might be better than matching  only spaces.

If you meant *up to* 10 times, that should be `{0,9}` instead of `{9}`.

<sup>1</sup> `\w` would match underscores, as well as various international letters, which your original pattern wouldn't. Wasn't sure if that was intentional, so I didn't use it, but if it wasn't intentional then `\w` is a better choice.

Comment: You could use the `\w` shortcut for the word characters.

Comment: ... which would include an underscore. Frankly, `\w` is a sad mistake that's just allowed to live on with little practical use.

Comment: @Bergi: I prefer it, but strictly speaking, as Joey says, it's not the same as `[a-zA-Z01-9]` so I left it as an option at the end.

Comment: That's right, yes. Don't think the OP wants only those 62 characters, he might include umlauts etc. to match "letter" characters.

Comment: @Bergi: I don't really think so either but I don't want to assume. I mentioned the umlauts and things because that's a really good point. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (with `()`) instead of [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) delimiters (`[]`) to group the expression that is to be [repeated](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) up to ten times:

```
^\w+(\s\w+){0,9}\s?$
```

Comment: You're missing the option of a trailing space. But anyway, other than that, I think this is a better pattern and I like the links.

Comment: Cool, now I can give you that +1. Didn't seem right to give it when the pattern wouldn't match what was asked, even though it was a great answer with all those links.